# liftEff Effect row type unification

Tags: purescript

I’m having a problem getting the following to compile:

```
module ContrivedExample where

import Prelude
import Data.Either (Either(..))
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Exception (EXCEPTION, throw)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (CONSOLE, log)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Class (liftEff)
import Control.Monad.Aff (launchAff)
import Control.Monad.Aff.Console (log) as A

contrivedExample :: forall e. Either String String -> Eff (exception :: EXCEPTION, console :: CONSOLE | e) Unit
contrivedExample a = do
       _ <- launchAff do
         _ <- A.log "yay"
         liftEff $ case a of
           Left e -> log e
           Right a -> throw a
       pure unit
```

I get this error:

```
Could not match type

    ( console :: CONSOLE
    | e3
    )

  with type

    ( exception :: EXCEPTION
    , console :: CONSOLE
    | t2
    )
```

If I remove exception from the Effect row, I get an error on the other side of the `Either`. Is there a better alternative to liftEff or some way I can unify the types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff/3.0.0/docs/Control.Monad.Aff#v:launchAff) of `launchAff`:

> Converts the asynchronous computation into a synchronous one. All
>   values are ignored, and if the computation produces an error, it is
>   thrown.
>
> Catching exceptions by using catchException with the resulting Eff
>   computation is not recommended, as exceptions may end up being thrown
>   asynchronously, in which case they cannot be caught.
>
> If you do need to handle exceptions, you can use runAff instead, or
>   you can handle the exception within the Aff computation, using
>   catchError (or any of the other mechanisms).

I believe you cannot throw exceptions inside `launchAff`, unless you also catch them inside the same computation.  You can only carry out other effects inside the `launchAff` computation otherwise.